# Is the following valid? $|x(t)|^2$

Tags: fourier-transform

$x(t)=\int_{-\infty} ^{\infty} X(jw)e^{jwt}dw$.

Where $X(jw)$ is the fourier transform of $x(t)$.

What is $|x(t)|^2$?

Can I say, it is $|\int_{-\infty} ^{\infty} X(jw)e^{jwt}dw|^2$, which is again, equal to $\int_{-\infty} ^{\infty}| X(jw)|^2|e^{jwt}|^2dw$= $\int_{-\infty} ^{\infty} |X(jw)|^2dw$

Is this valid?

Comment: $$\bigg\lvert \int X e^{jwt} dw \bigg\rvert \le \int \lvert X e^{jwt} \rvert dw \implies \bigg\lvert \int X e^{jwt} dw \bigg\rvert^{2} \le \int \lvert X e^{jwt} \rvert^{2} dw$$

Comment: @Mattos: Where did that inequality come from?